# google breakpad fails to compile for android under cygwin

Tags: android-ndk, cygwin, google-breakpad

I have a clean checkout of google breakpad from svn and am attempting to compile it using cygwin for android. It is not going well, however.

```
cd <google-breakpad>
android/run-checks.sh --ndk-dir=<my-ndk-dir> --tmp-dir=$PWD/bin --no-cleanup --no-device --verbose
```

I get an error `Can't build host-tools` due to:

```
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-Werror=non-virtual-dtor"
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-Werror=vla"
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-Werror=unused-variable"
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-Werror=missing-braces"
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-Werror=overloaded-virtual"
```

If I modify the makefile to remove these warning as error options, the build gets further, but fails to find a file that is clearly there:

```
Could not rebuild Android client library!
arm-linux-androideabi-g++.exe: /cygdrive/c/Users/Tom/dev/android/modules/google_breakpad/android/../src/client/linux/log/log.cc: No such file or directory
```

But:

```
$ ls -l /cygdrive/c/Users/Tom/dev/android/modules/google_breakpad/android/../src/client/linux/log/log.cc
-rw-r--r-- 1 Tom None 2.0K Jul 16 20:49 /cygdrive/c/Users/Tom/dev/android/modules/google_breakpad/android/../src/client/linux/log/log.cc
```

All files fail the same way - not just that one.

Any help appreciated.